# How do I get the SweetAlert-Variable to php?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I am very very new to PHP/JavaScript. So this question will be most probably very simple for most of you guys :) (Hopefully).

I have this standard Sweetalert2 Textbox and it looks amazing and opens like a treat. Now... I don't know how I could get the Variable "text" into a PHP- Variable, I need it in PHP, so that I can add it to my Database .... I know that I need to use AJAX ( something along these lines)`$.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "sweetalerttext.php", data: { 'text': text})`

but I don't know where exactly I have to add this AJAX code to my SweetAlert Code, nor do I know how I could set up my PHP File.....

I googled the last couple of days and I can't find a foolproof tutorial anywhere.

Would be super grateful if someone could help me out.
I added the JQuery to my header and the SweetAlert Files

Cheers

Moritz

```
//Sweet-Alert Code
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#new-btn').click(function () {

       async function getText () {
          const {value: text} = await swal({
              input: 'textarea',
              inputPlaceholder: 'Type your message here...',
              showCancelButton: true
          });

          if (text) {
              swal(text)
          }

      };
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place your AJAX call inside the `if` branch after the return from the `await` call. For example:

```
if (text) {
    $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "sweetalerttext.php", data: {'text': text}})
}
```

Comment: Thank you so so much, it worked like a charm :) If you ever need help in translating something to German, then PN me :)